# Stanfordnlp.download() fails: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

Tags: nlp, data-science, stanford-nlp

I simply tried to run the example given by stanfordnlp themselves:

```
>>> import stanfordnlp
>>> stanfordnlp.download('en')   # This downloads the English models for the neural pipeline
>>> nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline() # This sets up a default neural pipeline in English
>>> doc = nlp("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.  He was elected president in 2008.")
>>> doc.sentences[0].print_dependencies()
```

However, I was unable to do so, receiving the following error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nlp.stanford.edu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /software/stanfordnlp_models/latest/en_ewt_models.zip (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8f5dba7f10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

Why is this the case? I saw that this was an issue [on their github](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza/issues/426), but they stated that it was due to server issues which have sense been resolved. How can I solve this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stanfordnlp package is now deprecated. We renamed it to Stanza for more recent releases. You should follow the instructions here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/ . Following the corresponding steps there worked fine just now for me:

```
>>> import stanza
>>> stanza.download('en') # download English model
>>> nlp = stanza.Pipeline('en') # initialize English neural pipeline
>>> doc = nlp("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.") # run annotation over a sentence
>>> print(doc.entities)
```

That said, more details are:

- This error comes from failing to be able to download model data files from our lab machines. They are sometimes down. Try again the next day. Doing it right now, the model download succeeded fine (if a little slowly).
- `stanfordnlp` is incompatible with recent versions of PyTorch. If you see the error `RuntimeError: Integer division of tensors using div or / is no longer supported`, then you either need to switch to `stanza` or to downgrade your version of PyTorch to 1.5 or earlier
- Stanza downloads large model data files from GitHub rather than from our lab machines, and so Stanza model data file download should be more reliable. But if you have trouble accessing GitHub, see https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/faq.html#getting-requestsexceptionsconnectionerror-when-downloading-models